# Proper way to use LINQ for this type of query?

Tags: c#, linq

I was originally using a foreach loop and then for each element in the loop, I perform a LINQ query like so:

```
foreach (MyObject identifier in identifiers.Where(i => i.IsMarkedForDeletion == false))
{
    if (this.MyEntities.Identifiers.Where(pi => identifier.Field1 == pi.Field1 && identifier.Field2 == pi.Field2 && identifier.Field3 == pi.Field3).Any())
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Then I modified it like so:

```
if (identifiers.Any(i => !i.IsMarkedForDeletion && this.MyEntities.Identifiers.Where(pi => i.Field1 == pi.Field1 && i.Field2 == pi.Field2 && i.Field3 == pi.Field3).Any()))
{
   return false;
}

return true;
```

My question is this still the wrong way to use LINQ? Basically, I want to eliminate the need for the foreach loop (which seems like I should be able to get rid of it) and also make the DB query faster by not performing separate DB queries for each element of a list. Instead, I want to perform one query for all elements. Thanks!

Comment: What is the **type** of `identifiers`, `MyEntities` and `MyEntities.Identifiers`? Are they in memory collections or database entities?

Comment: Only the MyEntities.Identifiers is in the DB. Everything else is in memory.

Comment: In other words, `identifiers` is in memory collection, `MyEntities.Identifiers` is a `DbSet<Something>`.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I would use the `foreach` loop, as it's a lot easier to read.

Comment: And you are using EF6, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your modified version will be executed exactly the same way (i.e. multiple database queries) as in the original `foreach` approach because **EF** does not support database query with joins to in memory collection (except for primitive and enumeration type collections), so if you try the most logical way

```
bool result = this.MyEntities.Identifiers.Any(pi => identifiers.Any(i =>
    !i.IsMarkedForDeletion &&
    i.Field1 == pi.Field1 && i.Field2 == pi.Field2 && i.Field3 == pi.Field3));
```

you'll get

> **NotSupportedException**: Unable to create a constant value of type 'YourType'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

The only way to let **EF** execute a single database query is to manually build a LINQ query with `Concat` per each item from in memory collection, like this

```
IQueryable<Identifier> query = null;
foreach (var item in identifiers.Where(i => !i.IsMarkedForDeletion))
{
    var i = item;
    var subquery = this.MyEntities.Identifiers.Where(pi => 
        pi.Field1 == i.Field1 && pi.Field2 == i.Field2 && pi.Field3 == i.Field3);
    query = query != null ? query.Concat(subquery) : subquery;
}
bool result = query != null && query.Any();
```

See [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) of how to monitor the **EF** actions.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code in this way, and it will be converted to SQL statement as expected. 
To prevent runtime errors during transformation, it will be better to save DBSet to the IQueryable variable; `identifiers` should be IQueryable too, so you should change your code into something like this (to be honest, `Resharper` converted your `foreach` in this short labda):

```
IQueryable<MyObject2> identifiers = MyEntities.Identifiers.Where(i => i.IsMarkedForDeletion == false);
IQueryable<MyObject2> ids = MyEntities.Identifiers.AsQueryable();
return identifiers.All(identifier => !ids.Any(pi => identifier.Field1 == pi.Field1 && identifier.Field2 == pi.Field2 && identifier.Field3 == pi.Field3));
```

If `identifiers` is in memory collection you can change code in this way (hope that fields are `string`):

```
IQueryable<MyObject2> ids = MyEntities.Identifiers.AsQueryable();
string[] values = identifiers.Where(i => i.IsMarkedForDeletion == false).Select(i => String.Concat(i.Field1, i.Field2, i.Field3)).ToArray();
return !ids.Any(i => values.Contains(i.Field1 + i.Field2 + i.Field3));
```

Comment: Nope. It will **not** be converted to SQL, thus is equivalent to the original `foreach` approach

Comment: Could you provide information why do you think so? Because, I had practical experience and it works perfectly

Comment: Because just checked it - EF6.

Comment: Sorry, missed that `identifiers` is an inner collection. It should be IQueryable too.

Comment: Why do you use All instead of Any like I did above? Just curious.

Comment: All lists are stored in memory except for the one called "MyEntities.Identifiers". Basically what I am trying to do is find out if any rows in the DB contain the same Field1/Field2/Field3 combination as the identifiers (sorry should have called it something different than the MyEntities.Identifiers one to make it more clear).

Comment: Ok, changed it again. Hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would use it as follows:

```cs
if (identifiers.Where(i => !i.IsMarkedForDeletion &&     
this.MyEntities.Identifiers.Field1 == i.Field1 &&
this.MyEntities.Identifiers.Field2 == i.Field2 && 
this.MyEntities.Identifiers.Field3 == i.Field3).Any()))
{
   return false;
}

return true;
```

I hope this helps. Even though it is more to type out, it is more understandable and readable then using multiple 'where' statements.

Comment: I should have been more specific. MyEntities.Identifiers is a DB set of objects as opposed to just one object.